# Rails 3: create method inside a controller, Post.new instead of current_user.posts.build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, controller

I have this as my create method inside my PostsController

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = current_user
        @post  = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
        if @post.save
          flash[:success] = "Post created!"
          redirect_to root_path
        else
           @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
          render 'pages/home'
        end
      end
```

I'd like to change it slightly to also set :user_id => params[:post][:user_id]. I'm trying this but it doesn't include the current_user so I am wondering how are these create methods different and how would I keep the same functionality in current_user.posts.build(params[:post]) with Post.new ?

```
def create
  @post = Post.new :user_id => params[:post][:user_id]
  @post.update_attributes params[:post] 
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
    render 'pages/home'
  end
 end  
end
```

Comment: Just a note: depending on your intended purpose, you may not want the user id to be assignable by just about anyone? If not, then you should make user_id attr_accessible.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you elaborate on that a little more, I'm new at programming and rails so I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I understand attr_accessible allows for mass assignment from a form. I don't have user_id under my attr_accessible right now. I'm looking to set the post's user_id to the user_id of whomever created the post itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your post model belongs_to :user

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.user = current_user
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Post created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
    render 'pages/home'
  end
 end  
end
```

Comment: yes, I do have that relationship setup. Does @post.user = current_user do the same as :user_id => params[:post][:user_id]? I need to set the user_id first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need the post's user_id to be set first not after the Post.new(params[:post]), thats why i was trying the code above where @post.update_attributes params[:post] comes second